# How Do I Store Encrypted Settings in Qt/C++?

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, qtwidgets

I'm working with Qt and C++ for my very first time, doing a widget-based application for the Mac. Imagine a form with settings on it (checkboxes, radio buttons, fields) and I click Update to save these settings. I want to persist that data to an encrypted file so that other applications can't hack that file. What's the recommended technique? Also, what encryption method is best for this sort of thing?

Comment: The recommended method is to choose an encryption method, encrypt your settings into a buffer, then write that buffer to a file.  Read up on encryption and decryption techniques.

Comment: What method is secure and won't get me laughed out of the room? Too often I think I choose something strong, and then someone says, "Why did you do that? Nobody uses that anymore?"

Comment: Encryption will not prevent a file from being hacked.  Encryption reduces the quantity of hackers and maybe increases the amount of time to successfully hack a file.

Comment: If you're looking to store passwords, session tokens, etc. look into the Mac OS X Keychain feature. I don't believe Qt has any built-in way of accessing the Keychain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No encryption is necessary. You indicate that you are implementing this on a Mac, and OS-X is derived from BSD Unix, and you should have access to all the usual facilities that are provided by a UNIX/Posix based operating system.

Just install your application using a dedicated system userid, with your application being executable only by its userid, and the application files' permissions having the world-readable bit turned off. And you will have to log in to the application's userid, using any permissible method, such as manual password entry, or ssh keys, in order to run your application.

Your application is free to save its files without much afterthought. As long as their world-readable permissions are turned off, nothing else on the OS will be able to read it.